# clear ax2 in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot two lines with different scales with matplotlib.
It is currently working, except when I run my code the second Y axis messes up while updating.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
from matplotlib.pyplot import cm 
from datetime import datetime
import numpy as np    
import matplotlib.animation as animation

def animate(i, fig, ax):
# Converter function
    datefunc = lambda x: mdates.date2num(datetime.strptime(x, '%d-%m-%Y_%H:%M:%S'))

    # Read data from 'file.dat'
    dates, levels, temp = np.genfromtxt('datosPlot.txt',    # Data to be read
                                        converters={0: datefunc}, # Formatting of column 0
                                        dtype=float,   # All values are floats
                                        usecols=(0,1,2), #Leer las tres primeras columnas de datos.txt
                                        unpack=True)   # Unpack to several variables

    # Configure x-ticks
    ax1.clear()

    ax1.set_xticks(dates) # Tickmark + label at every plotted point
    ax1.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%d/%m/%Y %H:%M'))


    ax2 = ax1.twinx()

    fig.tight_layout()

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, fargs=(fig, ax1), interval=1000)
plt.show()
```

My data (`datosPlot.txt`) look like this:

```
14-01-2017_14:01:16 1 16
14-01-2017_14:01:19 14 22
14-01-2017_14:01:22 2 17
14-01-2017_14:01:25 4 19
14-01-2017_14:01:28 6 24
14-01-2017_14:01:31 12 19
14-01-2017_14:01:34 4 18
14-01-2017_14:01:37 9 20
```

First column is the X axis (date_time), second column is pH, third column is Temperature.

I've tried adding a `ax2.clear()` before and after calling `ax2 = ax1.twinx()`, but it doesn't work. How can I clear it, as I'm able with `ax1`?

Here is what it looks like when I don't add any `ax2.clear()`:
[image]

Comment: you should add dummy data to the example script instead of reading from `'datosPlot.txt'`, which no one but you has. Also remove all of the x-axis formatting since that is likely unrelated. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for more info

Comment: also, why is `ax1` a parameter to your function when you never use it? maybe both `ax1` and `ax2` should be parameter to your function and the function should not be responsible for creating them.

Comment: I added some dummy data as you suggested, @PaulH, also I removed some unnecessary information. About your second comment, I'm not sure I understand it, As far as I know, `ax1` and `ax2` are necessary to plot both lines (pH and temp) with their own scales (on the left and right of the graph)

Comment: just create arrays directly in your script, I don't want to have to parse your wacky data.

Comment: change `def animate(i, fig, ax):` to `def animate(i, fig, ax1):`. I mistyped my second comment. `ax` is the parameter to your function that you never use.

Comment: @PaulH The whole problem is completely unrelated to the function arguments. It's probably best to just omit them completely as I did in my anwer below in order not to create some unnecessary confusion.

Comment: Thank you, I'll give it a try as soon as I get home

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to create the axes outside of your animation and only use as little code as you really need in each animation step.

The following is a runnable example, where you would need to replace the read in function `em.genfromtxt()` with your original call to `np.genfromtxt(....)`.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
from datetime import datetime
import numpy as np    
import matplotlib.animation as animation


##### Emulator to generate data #########
class emulator():
    def __init__(self):
        self.dates = []
        self.levels = []
        self.temp = []

    def genfromtxt(self):
        self.dates.append(mdates.date2num(datetime.now()))
        self.levels.append(np.random.randint(1,14))
        self.temp.append(np.random.rand(1)*16+4)
        return self.dates, self.levels, self.temp

em = emulator()
##### End of Emulator to generate data #########




# Converter function
datefunc = lambda x: mdates.date2num(datetime.strptime(x, '%d-%m-%Y_%H:%M:%S'))


def animate(i):
    # Read data from 'file.dat'
    # instead we use an emulator here, replace with your original genfromtxt function
    dates, levels, temp = em.genfromtxt()

    # Configure x-ticks
    ax1.clear()
    ax2.clear()
    ax1.grid(True)
    ax2.grid(True)

    ax1.plot_date(dates, levels, ls='-', marker='.', color='red', label='pH')
    ax2.plot_date(dates, temp, ls='-', marker='.', color='blue', label='Temperatura C')

    ax1.set_xticks(dates) # Tickmark + label at every plotted point
    ax1.locator_params(axis='x',nbins=10)
    ax1.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%d/%m/%Y %H:%M'))
    #Leyendas
    lines = ax1.get_lines() + ax2.get_lines()
    plt.legend(lines, [l.get_label() for l in lines], loc=2)

    fig.autofmt_xdate(rotation=45)
    fig.tight_layout()



fig = plt.figure()

# we create both axes outside the animation and already set those parameters
# which stay the same throughout the animation.
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)

ax1.set_title('pH y Temp')
ax1.set_ylabel('pH')

ax2 = ax1.twinx()  # This should happen outside the animation already.
ax2.set_ylabel('Temperatura C')    

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval=1000)
plt.show()
```

Comment: This works great (it doesn't get messy anymore), the only thing is that it doesn't show the labels (`ax1.set_ylabel('pH')` and `ax2.set_ylabel('Temperatura C')`), any idea why?

Comment: I just figured it out, I moved those labels right after `ax1.plot_date(...)` and `ax2.plot_date(...)`, works perfect! thank you!